# Creating a loop for creating folders using python

Tags: python

I have to create folders from 1922 to 2010. For doing this I tried to create a loop as below

```
import os
year = 1922
for i in range(1921, 2010):
    path = os.mkdir("\\year")
```

The problem is how do I write year as 1922 in the folder path and keep increasing it till 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply format the result in:

```
import os
for year in range(1922, 2011):
    os.mkdir("\\{}".format(year))
```

Also note you don't need a separate year variable, this can be incremented by the for loop itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the folders in the same directory that the python module is being run from:

```py
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
for year in range(1921, 2010):
    os.mkdir(path + "\\" + str(year))
```

Alternatively, you can specify the path where you want to create the folders in the `path` variable

As of Python 3.6, you can also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals):

```py
os.mkdir(f"{path}\\{year}")
```

Comment: Saved me valuable time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't replaced inside ordinary strings. Either use string concatenation:

```
path = os.mkdir(r"\" + str(year))
```

or f-strings

```
path = os.mkdir(fr"\{year}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings very easily in python using the + operator.

I've also refactored your code a little to be more Pythonic:

```
import os
for year in range(1922, 2011):
    path = os.mkdir("\\"+str(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
for year in range(1921, 2011):
    os.mkdir("{}".format(year))
```